# How to set precision of double values to be of the form ##.## at ALL times?

Tags: java, formatting, double, precision

I am currently trying to create a timer for an android game which has the form ##.## at all times.

The issue I am having is that if my timer reaches say 23.50, it will set it as 23.5

So, I am trying to set the precision of my double value to be exactly 2 decimal places. This is my code so far, which doesn't work. Any suggestions are much appreciated, thanks.

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    double time1 = (double) millisUntilFinished/1000;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    timerDisplay.setText(df.format(time1));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```